# Backup data in Recovery mode on Android 3.2

Tags: samsung, backup, external-sd, boot-loop, samsung-galaxy-tab-7-plus

My **Samsung Galaxy Tab 7 plus(GT-P6200)** is stuck in boot loop.I have tried to solve the boot loop problem but couldn't succeed.The only solution seems to me is to format my phone and I am unable because of **important files**.I am able to go to the recovery mode.It shows the following options:-

reboot system now

*apply update from sdcard*

*apply update from cache*

*wipe data/factory reset*

*wipe cache partition*

*backup user data*

*restore user data*

Is there any way I can back up data on an external sdcard or on my PC? My android phone is not rooted.

Comment: backup user data looks good! hopefully it is not encrypted. try to unpack with bckp2win

Comment: Please how can I do that

Comment: insert MicroSD Card and select *backup user data* from recovery